# Using WHERE logic in CASE statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause, window-functions

Hi I'm very new to using Big Query and SQL and I'd like to use a case when statement in Big Query to create a new column. But I need to specify the selected value based on another column. So for example:

```
case when Y in (
                select Y
                from TABLE
                group by Y
                having count(distinct X) > 1) 
then X (where Z is max) end as new_column_value
```

Table Example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So in this example I want to identify rows where there is more than one X associated with a repeated Y value and then create a new column (shown below) where I choose one of the two ids based on the latest date. So the resulting column would be:

Example Output:

[image]

The where z is max section is where I get confused. I don't know how to put a "WHERE" clause logic, and I'm not familiar with any other alternatives to place into a "CASE" statement, in order to isolate specific values. Can someone please help me to figure this out?

Comment: Please add proper example with table description, data example and expected result. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: And if the query is for Big Query, why do you tag it as _Mysql_??

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z,
       FIRST_VALUE(X) OVER (PARTITION BY Y ORDER BY Z DESC) AS new_column_value
FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [RANK](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions)

[image]

Example excerpt from the docs:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY division ORDER BY finish_time ASC) AS finish_rank
```

Basically you will need to `RANK` over partition. I would advise you to use a `JOIN` between your main query and subquery, grouping by `Y`, instead of using a `case`-`when` in the `select` clause and then add this to your select

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Y ASC) AS new_column_value
```